# Is there a way to set value for a TextField in Flutter without setting selection or removing the selection after setting value?

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface, textfield

When we set `TextField` in Flutter via `TextEditingController` as follows:

```
textEditingController = TextEditingController();
textEditingController.text = "Some value.";
```

We know that the `text` setter here, would set `TextSelection` to the beginning of the input as seen in the following code:

```
 set text(String newText) {
    value = value.copyWith(
      text: newText,
      selection: const TextSelection.collapsed(offset: -1),
      composing: TextRange.empty,
    );
  }
```

My problem is that I don't want to set the selection, as after setting the `TextField` I am shifting focus onto another field.

So, is there any way to either set `TextField` value without setting selection or remove the set selection after setting the value?

Thanks.

Comment: `textEditingController.value = ...`

Comment: I tried textEditingController.text = "Some value."; but its not showing cursor on the textField

Comment: check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextEditingValue/TextEditingValue.html

Comment: Yeah, TextEditingValue without any selection would still set the selection to the beginning of the input by default.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a simple way to set value for a TextField programmatically, without selecting/focusing it?

Comment: ok so wher do you want the cursor to stay ? for example: you had text `foo` and now you set it to `foobar` so where should the cursor stay after setting the new value?

Comment: e.g. I have two fields and I set the value of the second one, upon making changes to the first one, But I don't want the second field to get focus or selection. I want the focus to remain on the first field.

Comment: @pskink My problem is a little different though, Both "Text Fields" are actually two separate stateless widgets containing `TextField` widget, sharing the same model, and the value is set by rebuilding the whole widget. So I want to set the initial value for a widget without setting focus/selection to it.

Comment: @pskink I want to set the initial value for a `TextField` without setting focus/selection on it.

Answer (score 0):

`textEditingController.value = TextEditingValue(text: "Some value.");`

Comment: Nope. TextEditingValue constructor by default sets the selection to the beginning of the input - 


const TextEditingValue({
    this.text = '',
    this.selection = const TextSelection.collapsed(offset: -1),
    this.composing = TextRange.empty,
  }) : assert(text != null),
       assert(selection != null),
       assert(composing != null);